# Solving a system of 6 simultaneous equations

Tags: equation-solving

Here is my code:

```
Solve[{A*p+A_1*q*r+γ*y-β*z==0, B*q+A_2*r*p+z*α-x*γ==0, C*r+A_3*p*q+x*β-y*α==0, 2*α+β*r-γ*q==0, 2*β+γ*p-α*r==0, 2*γ+α*q-β*p==0}, {p,q,r,α,β,γ}]//Simplify
```

However, it keeps on running but it does not give me a result. Is it because such a system is too complicated for Mathematica to solve or is there an error in the code?

Thanks

Comment: Don't use "underscore" in variable names!

Comment: Do not use capital C: it is reserved in Mathematica.

Comment: However, even after the errors are corrected, the code runs a very long time.  Mathematica often has trouble solving bilinear equations.

Comment: It is almost impossible to solve `q,r` when the equation contain `q*r`. for example `Solve[q*r==1,{q,r}]`. (Though we can use `Reduce`)

Comment: Also, please specify any constraints that may exist.  For instance, must the solutions be real, or are the constants all non-zero.

Answer (score 8):

Re-iterating:  Don't start user-defined variables with upper-case letter and the underscore is reserved for pattern matching.  Even if you change all the variables as I did below, without specifying values for the constants, I'm not optimistic  Mathematica will come up with a solution.  However, if you wish, you can study your system by supplying values for the constants.  In the code below, solutions are in the form of "Root" objects which in this case are roots to a 12-degree polynomial:

```
theA = 1;
a1 = 2;
a2 = 2;
a3 = 2;
theY = 3;
theZ = -1;
theB = -2;
theC = 3;
theX = 2;
Solve[{theA*p + a1*q*r + \[Gamma]*theY - \[Beta]*theZ == 0,
  theB*q + a2*r*p + theZ*\[Alpha] - theX*\[Gamma] == 0,
  theC*r + a3*p*q + theX*\[Beta] - theY*\[Alpha] == 0,
  2*\[Alpha] + \[Beta]*r - \[Gamma]*q == 0,
  2*\[Beta] + \[Gamma]*p - \[Alpha]*r == 0,
  2*\[Gamma] + \[Alpha]*q - \[Beta]*p == 0},
 {p, q, r, \[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma]}]
```

The solution took about a second to compute on my machine.